# Как работает Object assign если первое свойство пустой массив

Tags: javascript

В SO.EN я увидел такой код.

```
const
    data = [{ 0: { a: 1, b: 2 }, 1: { c: 3, d: 4 } }, { 0: { e: 5, f: 6 }, 1: { g: 7, h: 8 } }],
    flat = data.flatMap(o => Object.assign([], o));

console.log(flat);
```

[Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66034156/merged-array-objects-in-javascript/66034252#66034252)

Только вот негде не смог найти что за первый аргумент у `Object.assign`.Он же клонирует объект.В таком случае получается что он и деструктурирует его?

Негде не смог найти примеры использование `Object.assign` с пустым массивом. Если можно объясните как это работает и покажите примеры, пожалуйста. Чем больше примитивных примеров тем лучше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый параметр это [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) - Целевой объект.

> Метод Object.assign() копирует из исходных объектов в целевой объект
> только перечисляемые и собственные свойства. Он использует внутренний
> метод [[Get]] на исходных объектах и внутренний метод [[Set]] на
> целевом объекте, так что он также вызывает геттеры и сеттеры. Именно
> поэтому он присваивает свойства вместо простого копирования или
> определения новых свойств.

Примеры

```js
var obj = [{ a: 1 }];
var copy = Object.assign({}, obj);
console.log(copy); // {"0": { "a": 1 }}
```

разница

```js
var obj = [{ a: 1 }];
var copy = Object.assign([], obj);
console.log(copy); // [{ a: 1 }]
```